# Why are wave packets constructed so that the maximum probability occurs at K0 (the average wave number)?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, probability, wave-particle-duality, superposition

The definition of a wave packet I have been given is that it is "a superposition of many plane waves, with wave numbers grouped around an average value $k_0$".

I was told that, for a particle we want, its wave packet to be such that it has a maximum probability at $k_0$ - but I was under the impression that you integrate your probability density function with respect to position, not wave-number. Have I misunderstood the concept of a wave-packet? Could someone actually explain to me what they are?

edit: I'm asking about why we are considering values of the wave-number when determining the maximum probability of localising a particle in space and not the values of x(along the x-axis, if we think about it in one dimension). How would we relate the position of a wave and its wavenumber together? If you can do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relationship between a wave function and a wave packet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/403633/relationship-between-a-wave-function-and-a-wave-packet)

Answer (score 1):

For a [general wavepacket](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html)

[image: wavepacket]

A type of uncertainty principle exists for general wave equations:

[image: wavp2]

similar to the [Heisenberg uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html#c2) principle , HUP, for quantum mechanics.

[image: hup]

Interpreting the wave packet as a probability distribution,  if you control k, through the HUP you are also localizing x .

Comment: So is it like the probability function is the essentially the "wave function" of the particle and you use the probability function (which is y squared in the case of your photo) to determine where the particle is in space at time t or is it y is the actual equation for your particle and y itself determines how it moves?

Comment: it is a probability envelope in quantum mechanical systems